# nginx redirect by user login

Tags: authentication, nginx, redirect

I have a file "repoindex.xml". The name of the file has to stay the same. Now I need to redirect users by their username when authenticating to a custom location of a repoindex.xml which is only valid for the user currently login on.

Comment: Not sure by their username. Why would you want to though? Can you not to that from the application side and create a logic to redirect to a page based on their username? Because if the username changes then you would have to update the nginx configurations.

Comment: the application is not able to do that. the application does not even know about the users. so it is basically just plain http auth in nginx but there I need a logic because if I cannot solve that all users would have to use the same file. But the xml file properties do not allow me to do a seperation like I would need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a php file to solve this.

In the nginx vhost file I added

```
rewrite /repo/repoindex.xml /repo/repoindex.php last;
```

This is the repoindex.php

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['USER'] = "sles12sp3")
{
  $file = file_get_contents('./repoindex.xml_sles12sp3');
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file);
  echo $xml->asXML();
}
else if($_SERVER['USER'] = "sles12sp3-sap")
{
  $file = file_get_contents('./repoindex.xml_sles12sp3_sap');
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file);
  echo $xml->asXML();
}
else
{
 echo "No such User";
}
?>
```